# Coloring rows in Excel based on how many criteria are met

Tags: excel

I have just started working with the developer tab of Excel, and I need some help. I am trying to find an easier way to color rows on a sheet based on the number of criteria that is met. [Example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgiqz.png)

I could technically do this with Conditional Formatting. I actually started to do it before deciding how ridiculous it would be:

ALL

```
=AND(OR($D2>55, $G2<=1979),$E2="Male",OR($F2="Single",$F2="Widowed"),$L2>5,$M2>100)
```

MISSING ONE

```
= OR(AND(OR($D2>55, $G2<=1979),$E2="Male",OR($F2="Single",$F2="Widowed"),$L2>5), AND(OR($D2>55, $G2<=1979),$E2="Male",OR($F2="Single",$F2="Widowed"),$M2>100), AND(OR($D2>55, $G2<=1979),$E2="Male",$L2>5,$M2>100), AND(OR($D2>55, $G2<=1979), OR($F2="Single",$F2="Widowed"),$L2>5,$M2>100), AND($E2="Male",OR($F2="Single",$F2="Widowed"),$L2>5,$M2>100))
```

Don't bother looking into that too much. I'll explain the criteria: The perfect constituent is older than 55 OR graduated before 1979, is male, is widowed OR single, has five gifts or more, and has given $100 or more. If they meet the maximum of five of these, the row is highlighted orange. If they meet four, it's blue And so on~

Please ask questions if you have any. Thank you in advance!

Comment: why not just add a column with the desired formula and then use your conditinal formatting?`=if(condition,1,0)+if(condition,1,0)...`

Answer (score 1):

Much easier to count the number of true conditions.

Create conditional formats with the following formula:

```
=SUM(--($D2>55), --($E2="m"),--($G2<=1979),--(OR($F2="s",$F2="w")),--($L2>5),--($M2>100))=6
```

changing the number at the end for when `5`, `4`, `3`, `2`, `1`, or `0` of the conditions are true.

Answer (score 0):

Add five columns to the right of the "Criteria Met" . Each column /cell will process only one rule - and use Y or N.

Count the Number of Ys and then color the row.

Answer (score 0):

Here's [a solution](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Excel/Coloring-rows-in-Excel-based-on-how-many-criteria-are-met/m-p/357207/highlight/false#M26356) provided to me on the Microsoft Forums. It does exactly what I was looking for! Sergei Baklan replied:

```
=((OR(INDIRECT("Table1[@AGE]")>55,INDIRECT("Table1[@CLASS]")<1979))+(INDIRECT("Table1[@GENDER]")="Male")+(OR(INDIRECT("Table1[@STATUS]")="Widowed",INDIRECT("Table1[@STATUS]")="Single"))+(INDIRECT("Table1[@['# OF GIFTS]]")>=5)+(INDIRECT("Table1[@[TOTAL GIFT AMOUNT]]")>=100))=5
```

For the first rule, etc.